# onMessageReceived() is not called when app is in foreground

Tags: android, firebase

I am using following code to receive fcm message sent through firebase console, but this fucntion is never called. Instead I am able to receive message in my launcher class when the app is in background, but when the app is in foreground , I am not able to get it.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
String message="";
Map<String, String> m1;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //Displaying data in log
    //It is optional
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    System.out.println("---------------------");

    message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    m1= remoteMessage.getData();
    System.out.println("=============="+m1);
    System.out.println("=============="+m1.get("url"));

    //Calling method to generate notification
    //sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    //sendNotification_test(message);
   createNotification(m1,remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}


private void createNotification(Map<String,String> payload, String title){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);


    intent.putExtra("url",payload.get("url"));
    intent.putExtra("package",payload.get("package"));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(title)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

**Manifest**

```
 <service
    android:name="com.example.pranshusrivastav.fcmtest.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name="com.example.pranshusrivastav.fcmtest.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: what does your fcm message payload look like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i was putting the service declaration out of the application tag in manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.example.pranshusrivastav.fcmtest.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.example.pranshusrivastav.fcmtest.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
```

This worked !!

Answer (score 0):

try this'

```
    * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
    // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
    // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
    // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
    // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
    // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
    // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
    //
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    //The message which i send will have keys named [message, image, AnotherActivity] and corresponding values.
    //You can change as per the requirement.

    //message will contain the Push Message
    String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
    //imageUri will contain URL of the image to be displayed with Notification
    String imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
    //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as True then when the user taps on notification, in the app AnotherActivity will be opened. 
    //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as False then when the user taps on notification, in the app MainActivity will be opened. 
    String TrueOrFlase = remoteMessage.getData().get("AnotherActivity");

    //To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
    bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUri);

    sendNotification(message, bitmap, TrueOrFlase);

}
```

When sent using Firebase console, if the app is in the foreground then onMessageReceived() method will be called. Hence a notification with image an fetched from the url is displayed to the user . But if the app is background or killed state then onMessageReceived() method will not be called. Hence a simple notification containing just a message will be displayed in the notification bar of your android device.

you'll have to use

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIza************adrTY

{ "data": {
    "image": "https://ibin.co/2t1lLdpfS06F.png",
    "message": "Firebase Push Message Using API"
    "AnotherActivity": "True"
  },
  "to" : "f25gYF3***********************HLI"
}

Using Messaging API : To send a message using API, you can use a tool called AdvancedREST Client, its a chrome extension, and send a message with the following parameters.